# Error message when trying to insert method into touchesBegan

Tags: iphone, warnings, touchesbegan

I am trying to create a new method within my TapDetectingImageView file and it's giving me a warning that it cannot find the method even though I have it declared in the .h file.

The specific three warnings all point to the @end line in the .m file when I build it and they say: "Incomplete implementation of class 'TapDetectingImageView' ; 'Method definition for '-functionA:' not found" ; "Method definition for '-functionB:' not found"

What am I missing?  Am I not allowed to do this in a protocol file like TapDetectingImageView?

In my .h file is:

```
@interface TapDetectingImageView : UIImageView <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

id <TapDetectingImageViewDelegate> delegate;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <TapDetectingImageViewDelegate> delegate;

-(void) functionA:(NSString*)aVariable;
-(void) functionB:(NSString*)aVariable;

@end
```

In my .m file is:

```
-(void)functionA:(NSString*)aVariable {

// do stuff in this function with aVariable

}

-(void)functionB:(NSString*)aVariable {

// do stuff in this function with aVariable

}
```

Comment: did you import the appropriate header files?

Comment: Yep, the .m file imports the .h file where the methods are defined... it's something strange going on.  In any other .m and .h set, this works fine but it doesn't in TapDetectingImageView example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I had to declare them as private methods within the .m file in order for them to work and then call them as `[self methodName:variableIn]` ...for whatever reason they wouldn't work if I declared them in the .h file.

I declared them like this in the .m file right after the import files and before `implementation`:

```
@interface TapDetectingImageView()
// Private Methods
-(void)functionA:(NSString *)aVariable;
-(void)functionB:(NSString *)aVariable;
@end
```